# What is the difference in atomic_load() and assignment?

Tags: c11, rvalue, stdatomic, lvalue-to-rvalue

I am working on a project that deals with lots of atomic operations. Till now I didn’t knew about `atomic_load()` and was only relying on assignment operator to get value of an atomic type and I haven’t seen an error except of so much of testing. Those atomic types are changed by multiple processes and threads as well by `atomic_compare_exchange_strong_explicit()`, so they will need an old value every time, and that’s where I always did `oldValue = <Atomic_ type_variable>` and it always works fine.
Is that just by chance? Should I prefer using atomic_load()?

Comment: What ordering do you need?

Comment: I am not really familiar wit memory orderings(really confusing). Maybe that’s in atomic_load_explicit(). My question was regarding just atomic_load(), for which someone gave the answer.

Comment: You are confused? So his everybody, I believe. There are arguments by researchers that the specification of relaxed ordering is defective in a deep way!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**`foo = atomic_var` is just a shortcut syntax for `foo = atomic_load(&atomic_var);`**

Which itself is a shortcut for `foo = atomic_load_explicit(&atomic_var, memory_order_seq_cst);`  *That* has a use-case when you want to use an ordering weaker than the default `seq_cst`.

The main reason for using `atomic_load` explicitly in your source code is probably to remind human readers that a variable or pointer *is* atomic.  Or maybe as a part of a macro, using `atomic_load(&(macro_input))` would create a compile-time error for a non-atomic pointer.

As a "generic" function, you can't take a normal function-pointer to it.

Its existence may be just to make it easier to write the language standard, and explain everything in terms of functions.

---

**It's not the actual *assignment* that's key here, it's evaluating the atomic variable in an rvalue context** (reading it's value as part of an expression, like you typically find on the right-hand side of an `=`).  `printf("%d\n", my_atomic_var);` is also equivalent to `atomic_load`.

---

And BTW, the same thing holds for `atomic_var = foo;` being exactly the same as `atomic_store_explicit` with `mo_seq_cst`.  Here it *is* assignment that's key.

Other kinds of lvalue references to an atomic variable are different, like read-modify-write `atomic_var++` is equivalent to `atomic_fetch_add`.